# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, owin

Upon running in local my website has the below error.

I have checked the DLLs, its the latest 4.2.0.

## LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
(Fully-specified)
Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Nugets which i have upgraded:

- Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.4.2.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.4.2.0
- Microsoft.Owin.4.2.0
- Owin.1.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.2.4.2
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.2.4.2
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.2.4.2
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS.2.4.2

I have checked the binding the web.config, all seems to be correct.

Reinstalled via the nuget. Still cant overcome the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to remove the xmlns to just  and it working thank you.

<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"

Answer (score 2):

Change the version of, Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0 to Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.2.0.0

Comment: I have changed from 2.1.0.0 to 4.2.0.0, which is why ended up with the error. Where is trying to get the 2.1.0.0 version instead of 4.2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I am also using SignalR.

The only solution is to downgrade the Microsoft.OWIN family back to 2.1.0. Now my site is working fine .

[image]