Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin Version=3.0.1.0
execution of my web applications fails with following runtime error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Assembly load trace:
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/GIT/Site/Portal/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Projects\GIT\Site\Portal\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===

Nowhere in my application do i have a reference to version 3.0.1.0 of Owin.  I have no idea where this error is coming from
My packages.config looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Crestron.NP.Legacy" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Crestron.NP.Legacy.Wrappers.Telerik" version="2024.2.513" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Crestron.NP.System.Enum" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Crestron.NP.System.Security" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="4.19.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.8.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.7.1" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.13.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices" version="2.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.37.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Radius" version="2.0.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="RazorEngine" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.Compression.Base" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.DocIO.Wpf" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.DocToPDFConverter.Wpf" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.ExcelToPdfConverter.Wpf" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.HtmlToPdfConverter.WPF" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.Licensing" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.OfficeChart.Base" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.Pdf.Wpf" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Syncfusion.XlsIO.Wpf" version="27.1.51" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Dynamic" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net45" requireReinstallation="true" />
</packages>

I have already use the clean option in visual studio, deleted the obj and bin folders from my webapp.  Error keeps persisting
any ideas?

Is this a framework app? If so, make sure you're referencing your package.config file and not your web.config file.

how do i do that?

Version=3.0.1.0, in the error is Assembly version.  ..... <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.2" is package version ... you need to go to your nuget stash and find assembly version of the DLL using a tool dotPeek or ILDASM (comes with VS)

you must know what your target framework is, your project style is etc. You must supply all this data, better yet, ENTIRE proj file

This question is similar to: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/39276347/109941

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70458046/109941

You do have a reference to

Another package must have a dependency on version 3.0.1.0
Try and update the package to version 3.0.1.0

But this would not be an update, this would be a downgrade since i'm using 4.2.2?
